# How to launch a second JFrame from clicking a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm making a To-Do List application and I have a PrimaryList frame and a SubList frame. When a user selects something from the PrimaryList (Grocery...or something like that) and then hits a forward arrow JButton, it is supposed to launch up the SubList frame. Now here is what I have for the actionPerformed method of the forward arrow button called btnArrow.

```
private void btnArrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    lstToDoLists.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
            if (lstToDoLists.getSelectedIndex() > 0){
                btnArrow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
                        if (btnArrow==ae.getSource()){
                            SubList sublist = new SubList();
                            sublist.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }            
    });
}
```

Now, when I run the PrimaryList file and click on an item in my JList and then select the forward arrow button, I get nothing. But then when I click another element from the list and press the forward arrow button again, my SubList pops up twice.

Something isn't write with what I've written and I am hoping someone else will know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding listeners inside of listeners -- something that you don't want to do, since this means that new listeners will be added, each time an event occurs.

Solution: don't add listeners inside of other event listeners but rather add the listeners once and in your code's constructor or initialization method.

Note that I would not use a `ListSelectionListener` at all. Instead I'd just use a single ActionListener on the button. Then in that listener, get the list's selection and use it.

e.g.,

```
private void btnArrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    // if list contains String:
    String selectedItem = (String) lstToDoLists.getSelectedItem();

    // check that selectedItem isn't null, i.e, 
    if (selectedItem != null) {
        // TODO: do something with selection here
    }
}
```

As a side recommendation, please look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).

Comment: What would I put then in my initalization method?

Comment: @PhilDrach: it's hard to say since you've posted just a small snippet of code. Better to post a very small compilable program that reproduces your problem. But bottom line is that you'd take care to add your listeners only **once**.

Comment: @PhilDrach: also note that I would not use a ListSelectionListener at all. Instead I'd just use a single ActionListener on the button. Then in that listener, get the list's selection and use it.

Comment: @PhilDrach: for example

Comment: Last question, in your example code where you have '// do something with selection here', how do I send the selection to be registered by the button?

Comment: @PhilDrach: Define "send the selection..."? You've got the selection in a variable, selectedItem. Do whatever you need to with that variable.